# How to handle timeout in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, timeout

How can I handle exception if response time is greater than specific time limit in apache camel.
Example: My service timeout should handled before threshold of 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

it depends to your webserver . if you use standart spring boot application u must configure apache tomcat for quarkus it vert.x